Blazor hybrid LocalStorage consume into CS class file
So this is my razor code file
@inject Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService localStorage
var test = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<String>("MyKey");

And this WORKS.
So i need to get the data into Utility.cs class
internal class Utility
 {
     protected readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorage;
     public Utility(ILocalStorageService LocalStorage)
     {
         _localStorage = LocalStorage;
     }

     public async Task updateLocalStorage()
     {
         await _localStorage.SetItemAsync("test", "123");
     }

     public async Task getLocalStorage()
     {
         ResponseLogin login = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<ResponseLogin>(LocalStorageNames.ResponseLogin);
     }
 }

and into MauiProgram.cs i added this:
builder.Services.AddScoped(p => new Utility(p.GetRequiredService<ILocalStorageService>()));

But, i didn't understand why my Utility class keep null when i start.. i can't understand how to init this class
Utility _utility = new Utility(????);

Any help? I need to use this class like a singleton
Also tried this:
[Inject]
public blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService localStorage { get; set;}

But always null...

I need to use this class like a singleton    Have you tried method builder.Services.AddSingleton ?  For more information, please check: .NET dependency injection ?

@JessieZhang-MSFT yes i've tried but nothing...i can't understand how to init the localstorage

There is a similar problem, you can check it first here: Inject LocalStorage in C# file.

Have you tried [Inject] private Utility utility { get; set; }?
